# How to backup (make a copy of) LiveCD changes?

Tags: filesystems, backup, livecd, overlayfs

Many LiveCD distributions (for example Lubuntu 12.10 I use) allow making changes, for example updating timezone, logging in to Google Chrome, updating and installing additional packages such as OpenVPN.  They do that by overlaying read-write filesystem, in my case RAM-based tmpfs (or ramdisk, or ramfs, or USB pendrive), over CD-ROM based filesystem, in my case system image via squashfs but might be iso9660 or udf directly, using some union filesystem, in my case overlayfs (or unionfs, or aufs).

I'd like to make copy of changes (e.g. using `dd`) and only changes of an existing running LiveCD (e.g. Lubuntu 12.10) and I don't want to make copy of whole '/' mountpoint, including both changes and original CD-ROM. How can I find device or mountpoint which I can point e.g. `dd` to?

`mount` shows the following (excerpt):

```
/cow on / type overlayfs (rw)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
/dev/sr0 on /cdrom type iso9660 (ro,noatime)
/dev/loop0 on /rofs type squashfs (ro,noatime)
tmpfs on /tmp type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
```

---

*Original question*: [Persisting changes on Lubuntu 12.10 run from LiveCD](https://askubuntu.com/q/295031/106820) on *Ask Ubuntu* (no answers as of posting this one).

Comment: Look at the `mount` output, the CD and some RAM are mounted as `unionfs`. Instead of the RAM you could use a USB stick.

Comment: But from the above (just added) output, which is filesystem / device that is overlaid over squashfs?

Comment: How about creating a bootable usb stick with unetbookin - http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/ - and using the "persist data" option?

Comment: The problem is not creating or selecting LiveCD / LiveUSB (thanks for the advice, @nwildner) with persistent changes (saved on hard disk or USB pendrive), the problem is backup of data from LiveCD I am using.

Comment: Ah, ok. I got the idea now. It is about making a backup of the pendrive, not a backup of what is modified with the live distro booted up. Well, if you have 2 equal pendrives(manufacturer and model) a dd could be enough to make a backup(`dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdd bs=10M conv=notrunc`). I'm still thinking if there is a way to make a filesystem level backup of it...

Comment: No, it is about backup of changes to booted up *running* live distro (I edited the question to be more precise).

Comment: Look at this distributive http://www.slax.org/en/documentation.php#booting

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu sticks, look for a file called `casper-rw` while the stick is not booted. That file should contain the changes.